# Chrome ненужная перезагрузка страницы history api

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, ajax, javascript, history-api

Вот код отлавливания событий он работает нормально кнопка назад работает. но в chrome есть недостаток этот скрипт срабатывает при перезагрузки страницы( f5 или кнопка) . и получается страница загружается два раза первый по средством php второй посредством этого скрипта .
Так вот вопрос как ограничить chrome от ненужной перезагрузки через этот скрипт?.

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
    title(history.state.url);
    open(history.state.url);
});
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421769/popstate-on-pages-load-in-chrome

Comment: Все очень просто я решил задачу window.y="true";
в функции открытия а здесь проверка если было открытия страницы то все будет работать а если не то нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте state у полученного события:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {        
        if (e.originalEvent.state) open(history.state.url);

    });
    function open(url) {        
        $('#out').append($('<p>',{text:'pop:'+url}));
    }
    $('button').click(function() {
        var url='?'+Math.random();
        var state={url: url,title: "title"};
        window.history.pushState(state,"T:"+url,url);
        $('#out').append($('<p>',{text:'push:'+url}));
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7tUV4/

http://fiddle.jshell.net/oceog/7tUV4/show/

Answer (score 0):

Забыл `return false;`:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
  ...
  return false;
});
```